# Is a linear operator uniquely defined by its matrix in a particular basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space. Can a linear operator $F:V\to V$ be uniquely defined by specifying its matrix in a particular basis? I am thinking yes, because if $B$ is a basis, and $G:V\to V$ is another linear operator such that $[F]_B = [G]_B$ then we have for an arbitrary vector $u\in V$ that
$$
[F]_B[u]_B = [G]_B[u]_B \Longleftrightarrow [Fu]_B = [Gu]_B,
$$
and since there there is a one to one correspondance between V and the coordinate vectors in the basis B we find that
$$
Fu = Gu \Longleftrightarrow F = G.
$$

Comment: Sure! I suppose You are talking about finite-dimensional vector spaces?